# Print out JSON with multiple arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have this JSON string that has been converted into a PHP array:

```
Array (
    [textfield] => Array (
        [elements] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                [type] => textField
            )
        )
        [title] => textfield
    )
    [textarea] => Array (
        [elements] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                [type] => textArea
            )
        )
        [title] => textarea
    )
) textfield
```

And I'm trying to loop through it and print out the `type` and `title` of each array. This is what I have so far:

```
foreach($inputs as $key => $jsons) {
    foreach($jsons as $key => $value) {
        echo $value;
    }
}
```

But that only prints out the `title`. Note, I do actually need to loop through the array and get all the values because I need to use them, I know I could use `print_r` to just dump the array but that's not what I need!

Comment: See my answer. I'll update it once you show how you need $elements[x]['type'].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an easy way... but without seeing more of what you're trying to do, who knows if this will even work.

```
foreach($json as $key => $value) {
  $elements = $value['elements'];
  foreach($elements as $key => $element) {
    echo "$key = {$element['type']}\n";
  }
  $title = $value['title'];
  echo "$key = $title\n";
}
```

Comment: This prints out the `title` element, but I also need to print out the `type` within each element of the `elements` array.

Comment: Updated answer for you.

Comment: It's complaining about a `String to Array` conversion where you `echo` the `$element`. Which makes no sense since that should loop through the array correct?

Comment: Ah, forgot that `$element` is an array.. fixed answer.

Comment: No problem.. Keep in mind that I have specified `$element['type']` in a static manner... which may or may not work for you... but if `$element` will always have a `type`-keyed array item, then it should be fine.. just something to be aware of for the future.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($inputs as $key => $jsons) {
    foreach($jsons as $key1 => $value) {
          if( $key1 == "title" ) {
                echo "TITLE :-".$value;
          } else if( is_array($value) {
                foreach($value as $key2 => $value2) {
                     echo "Type :".$value;
                }
          }
     }
}
```